# SOAP-ERROR while loading external entitiy

Tags: php, web-services, ubuntu, soap, wsdl

I am getting this Error at Server but not at my local machine:

**SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx?WSDL"**

My Server and my local OS both are UBUNTU. 
Server PHP version is 5.3.5 and 
My Local machine PHP version is 5.4.2.
Now is it only happened for PHP version or any other reason?

Any kind of help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: How about removing the soap element for a moment. Can you login and  wget the file from the command line on the remote machine?

Comment: Yes I can access this file via wget at remote machine. @Cups

Comment: How about 1. Checking the validity of the wsdl or even 2. temporarily caching the wsdl file on the rogue machine and turn wwsdl caching to ON. I'm sorry I cannot think of much else.  There may be an issue with https:// soap connections of which I have no experience to share. Sorry.